# Measure similarity between text documents

Tags: python, nlp, topic-modeling

I have 10000 questions framed in different ways, and I want to find the top 20 most frequently asked questions. What would be the best method to do so? So far I'm juggling with

1. topic modelling like BERTopic or NMF or
2. finding text similarity with cosine similarity metrics or
3. using like k-means clustering or hierarchical clustering

Since I'm new to this field, I might be missing something obvious (either a method or an existing software/package that deals with this specifically).

Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow is a site for specific questions with specific answers for which you can provide a [mcve], and questions asking for tools, libraries, or other off-site resources are explicitly off-topic for SO. This question would be a better fit on a general discussion forum. That said, it seems like you have some good avenues to start exploring, and then to come back and ask a specific question if you get stuck

Comment: *"I have 10000 questions framed in different ways"* It's unclear to me what this 10000 number refers to: the number of distinct questions, or the total number of questions including duplicates?

Comment: You present "topic modelling", "text similarity" and "clustering" as three alternatives. But it looks to me like they should be used together. The exact clustering algorithm you use is largely irrelevant. The one thing that is relevant is: how to determine whether two questions are similar?

Comment: @G.Anderson Fair point, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Stef 10000 refers to number of distinct questions.

Comment: And to your other comment: Methodologically these are three different approaches to determining text similarity. How come the clustering method is irrelevant? Some has to be more suitable than others since we are not dealing with comparison of large documents but 300-500 character texts.

Comment: @Quantizer No, they are not three different methods for the same problem. They are three different methods for three different problems, and the reality is that your problem is going to need at least two of them. For instance, k-means clustering only makes sense if you already have a method to determine text similarity. Otherwise, how is k-means clustering going to know which sentences to put in a cluster together?

Comment: @Quantizer But the subproblem where your choice will really matter is how to define text similarity. This is what is going to have a big impact on your results.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this code with randomly generating quations and applying KMeans clustering to find the most requantly asked questions. Please first install `pip install scikit-learn`.
Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

import random

topics = ["technology", "health", "politics", "food", "travel", "sports"]
keywords = ["best", "how", "what", "why", "when", "where"]
verbs = ["improve", "choose", "avoid", "cook", "visit", "watch", "play"]
nouns = ["phone", "diet", "policy", "restaurant", "destination", "game"]

questions = []

for i in range(10000):
    topic = random.choice(topics)
    keyword = random.choice(keywords)
    verb = random.choice(verbs)
    noun = random.choice(nouns)
    question = "{} {} {} {}?".format(keyword.capitalize(), verb, noun, topic)
    questions.append(question)


# Preprocess the questions and create a document-term matrix
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',
                             lowercase=True,
                             token_pattern='[a-zA-Z]+',
                             min_df=10)
doc_term_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(questions)

# Apply KMeans clustering
num_clusters = 20
km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
km.fit(doc_term_matrix)

# Compute the frequency of the clustered questions
labels = km.labels_
cluster_counts = {}
for label in labels:
    if label not in cluster_counts:
        cluster_counts[label] = 1
    else:
        cluster_counts[label] += 1

# Identify the top 20 most frequent clusters
top_clusters = sorted(cluster_counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:20]

# Print the questions in the top 20 clusters
for i, cluster in enumerate(top_clusters):
    print("Cluster {} ({} questions)".format(i+1, cluster[1]))
    for j, question in enumerate(questions):
        if labels[j] == cluster[0]:
            print("{}. {}".format(j+1, question))
    print()
```

The code will hopefully give you the excepcted output. If you have any questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: Just of out curiosity: Why did you choose k-means clustering as the method? What makes you thank that is the most suitable method?

Comment: i think that this was the most efficient way to solve the problem. If you want to do it by another method, I can do that too.